# Cannot connect to AWS EC2 nginx

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 instance , and inbound/outbound security like:
[image: inbound]

and '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default' setting is:

```
server {
        listen 8080 default_server;
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name  _;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
}
```

I try to use `curl` to test , and it's work.
[image]

I don't know why I can't connect from local ?
[image]

Comment: Are you creating the instance in the default VPC with default ACL?

Comment: @Gapton 
I start a new ec2 , then install nginx and listen 8080, it's work . then , I install apache2 (default 80) , and apache work , but nginx is not working.